# What are the skills required to have a successful career as a police officer?

Tags: india, skills

I am about to complete my B.Sc degree and I wanted to be a police officer since last 7 years. Now that I have been disillusioned that life can be easy thanks to SARSCOV2, I want to know what technical skills and soft skills that I can learn **before** I apply to police academy.

I would like to add that I am just 20 years old and the BSc program we have in Republic of India (South Asia) is of three and not of four years as observed in USA. I would like to revisit my knowledge of basic skills that help with employment in police agencies  and generally leave positive impression on employers. Time management, communication skills to name a few. I would like to say I am not overenthusiastic but I have talked about it with cops and I would like to have a fundamental revision about list of skills preferred/useful on duty and how can one acquire them. Thank you.

Further details are below.

I have no previous job experience yet I want to get in police force. By the unsaid 'competitive' aspect of my question I would like to tell that everyone would need a job to be able to sustain themselves.

I have problems with my visual acuity and I don't expect my parents to support me for longer than a few years from now. I am in a dilemma between taking steps to pursue my M.Sc and risk being overqualified -- therefore defeating the whole purpose of doing Master's -- and not doing anything productive in between [extraocular surgery](https://www.britannica.com/science/strabismus) I will certainly need before applying. I would like to say I would like to do anything ethical **and** internationally lawful because Covid-19 is not helping economy and **I know it is not about just me but I also need a job to feed myself and *I am eager  to serve my country and I hope to do that as a police officer***

To become a police detective specifically, what skills can help as a candidate or be generally useful on duty? Thank you. I would like to say that I want to become a Police Sergeant (Police Sub Inspector here) if it helps.

Comment: Grammar etc still needs improving. Also BSc is usually 3 years in UK.

Comment: I regret I did not specify whether I want to be join at which rank and at which branch. I left those important details in a rush. To be honest I am just worried about my squint... and it is ""not"" that I want only a job in police but to be honest cops are my heroes and especially during these uncertain times... I have spoken to many cops but unfortunately I forgot the specific details about strabismus and thus I am nervous.

Comment: Yes, about the brochure-type documents, there is no  special reference to strabismus/squint WHICH gives me a lot of hope. However I will be very grateful if I receive your regional/national guidelines also because I have found out many things are same there and also here. I.e. to become an FBI agent you'd need to be at least 21 years of age and also it's same here for IPS officers (top-level officers) Please inform me if you have knowledge about squint with reference to management rank (not necessarily chief rank)

Comment: Thank you a LOT for your (uplifting) answer @Fattie. I would once again like to clarify myself that history of squint is not an automatic permanent disqualification? As mentioned to the answer below I have 6/6 eyesight in both eyes with glasses with no difference in worse eye/better eye.

Comment: hello @ToraneHS - that information would surely depend on your local area!  I encourage you to search about it online?  Good luck !!

Comment: Thank you. I gained outsight. If i am disqualified for one reason or another I will try to become  a college professor  and thus do my part. One thing I learnt after posting this question is that I should apply first and then see for myself. However still I have learned that history of squint is not referred in relevant documents/brochures. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contact a recruiter in your area. Many police departments go to high schools or colleges and recruit students.  Most police departments have a website telling you the requirements, and the process.

In many (most) police departments the detective path is different than the leadership path. But they can tell you what the basic requirements including education, time, and training you need for those career choices.

You may find that in your local area there can be multiple police organizations. In the US we have county/city police; state police; and the FBI. There are also some places that don't have a police department, all the local police functions are handled by the sheriff department. Each organization will have different requirements and opportunities.

To be successful depends on what are your goals. Some officers always want to be a street cop, others want to be the chief. Each has different requirements. Start with a recruiter they can give you concrete answers.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. However we do not have individual recruiters in Republic of India as far as my knowledge goes, there the Govt only advertises  and I must communicate very methodically if I want to reach them. Do you know any cases if/when a person who has gone through strabismus surgery/ squint surgery is rejected? As far as my knowledge goes that is not specified in any of the official documents for recruitment with special reference to squint on official websites. Is it also the case in the USA? My vision is 6/6 in both eyes with glasses so no problem with LASIK, etc.

Comment: Through discussion my question was answered and thus I've selected the answer as useful. Thank you.

Comment: @ToraneHS, The police force in India is bound to have an HR office. Whether those HR people want to talk to you, or not, is a different matter, but those people exist and they're the right people to contact about your question. If I were you, I would keep on calling them, try different numbers if you have to, and ask them to forward you. If that doesn't work, ask the help of a police officer, if a police officer tells you to call them, then you can invoke the name of that police officer when you talk to them and say "So-and-so told me to call you directly to ask you a question I have".

Answer (score 1):

*As soon as possible,* I think that you need to speak to the **actual** police departments who might hire you.  Let *them* assess your suitability ... let *them* tell you about your eye condition and about your advanced college degree.  It is "all too easy" to, so to speak, "box yourself into a corner *of your own making."*  You think that you understand things clearly, but the reality is that you don't – and, *can't.*

Also: ***I salute you*** for your willingness to serve your community, in the corner of the planet that you are now in.  I wish you the very best of success, *and* safety.  "Ordinary citizens" owe every one of you a debt of gratitude that we typically do not express. ***Thank You,*** in advance.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, salutation and great amount of respect. According to my current situation I would like to have a first hand experience in becoming a police officer. I will go with a trial-and-error method of giving the recruitment examination soon and then see how I can qualify. About my medical history, I have yet to undergo any surgery and I am going to talk to the doctor about my condition and eligibility to serve. There I will surely get a considerable medico-legal opinion. Thank you.